# How to think of analytic varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the following definition:

> A subset $V$ of an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is an *analytic variety* in $U$ if for any $p\in U$ there is a neigborhood $U'$ of $p$ in $U$ such that $V\cap U'$ is the common zero locus of a finite collection of holomorphic functions $f_1,...,f_k$ on $U'$.

I'm wondering about the part that $U$ plays here. I've seen some online references that simply state that an analytic variety is a set locally defined as the zero locus of holomorphic functions, but this is not exactly the case (this would be a *locally analytic set*, according to [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/analyticset)).

I realize that $V$ is realtively closed in $U$, but what else? For instance, do we expect $V$ to be dense in $U$, or do we allow $V\cap U'=\emptyset$?

Any insight as to why analytic varieties are more interesting to research than locally analytic sets would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set

$$X=\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\cdots \right\} \subset\mathbb{C}$$

is an analytic set of $U=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ but is not an analytic set of $\mathbb{C}$. So, with the $U$ we have a more general definition.